# Yii CPasswordHelper как использовать?

Tags: yii

Не могу понять, как делать.
Покажите, пжс, наглядно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://des1roer.blogspot.ru/2015/02/yii.html

Comment: @anunak, ну вы сами выбрали себе инструмент, чего тут удивляться $_POST в модели.